# PDF in android for API 17+

Tags: android

Please, how do i display a pdf stored in my assets folder in my application.  I have tried looking around but i see PdfRenderer supports  AP1 21. I want to support API 17 and upwards. Thanks.

i have tied a few samples

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment
   .getDataDirectory(), "file:///android_asset/abstract.pdf");

    try {

        if (pdfFile.exists()) {

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
            Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(objIntent);
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(WebShow.this, "File NotFound",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        Toast.makeText(WebShow.this,

                "No Viewer Application Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

i saw online but i don't know how to get around it (.getDataDirectory())because i get "file not found"

Answer (score 0):

I have it working on mine, just using simple logic.
get the file path as string. also, you may want to check your file Path as well.

```
String pdfFile= SdCardpath + "/" + Filepath + Filename;
File file = new File(pdfFile);
```